# Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Tags: intellij-idea, manifest, executable-jar, securityexception

I'm using `Intellij Idea 13` and I followed the instruction on how to create an executable jar.
After that I got my jar and my manifest but everytime I double-click the jar file I get

''A Java Exception Occured''

and when I try to launch it using `''java -jar File-Name.jar''` it says :

```
''Exception in thread ''main'' java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes''
```

The thing is that when I launch it using Intelij Idea, it work well, no `exception` or anything like that.

Does anybody know what's the problem and how I can solve it?